# Valgrind reports SIGSEGV and use of uninitialised value

Tags: c, string, memory-leaks, valgrind

Edit: All valgrind errors where solved by initialising `i`.

---

I am working with strings; reading strings from a file, separating them using `strsep()`, converting them to int using `atol()`. My code compiles on gcc and runs without errors, but when checked with valgrind I get the error mentioned in the title.

I am trying populate a two-dimensional array `grid[20][20]` with int values from a text file. The text file contains lines of numbers separated by spaces, something like `20 81 65 07 54 72 13 28 66 95 00 20 00 84 06 30 85 43 15 73\n`

My code, (excluding all of the file IO) is as below. (Note that I do handle the file correctly: checking the result of `fopen`, closing with `fclose`).

#### Updated code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define STR_LEN     20
#define NUM_LINES   20
#define MAX_SIZE    100

int main(void){
    char input_str[MAX_SIZE];   //string to hold lines read from file
    char * str_array[STR_LEN];  //array of strings to split the lines into
    int grid[20][20];
    char * token, *str, *tofree;
    int line;
    for (line = 0; line < NUM_LINES; ++line){   //for every line in the file 
        
        if (fgets(input_str, MAX_SIZE, fp)!=NULL){  //read the file's line into input_str
            tofree = str = strdup(input_str);   //set str to copy of input_string, and tofree to point to beginning of str's memory, to free later
            
            int i = 0;
            while ((token = strsep(&str, " "))){    //split str on " ", keeping everything in between in token
                str_array[i] = token;   //add token to str_array
                ++i;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < STR_LEN; ++i){
                grid[line][i] = atol(str_array[i]); //convert strings to int and store in num_array     
                printf("grid[%d][%d]: %d\n", line, i, grid[line][i]);

            }
            free(tofree);   //free str by freeing tofree, as tofree points to str's memory
        }
    }
    printf("%d", grid[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this code with `gcc -Wall -g -c myfile.c`. It both compiles and runs fine, with no errors. Checking the values using `printf()` just after the values have been passed to `grid` shows all correct values. *However*, the last `printf()` in the code shows that `grid[0][0]` contains junk, even though it was correct before. In fact, all elements in `grid[0]` have been corrupted.

Running valgrind with `valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --dsymutil=yes --show-leak-kinds=all ./productGrid.elf` gives me

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --dsymutil=yes --show-leak-kinds=all ./productGrid.elf

==2252== Command: ./productGrid.elf
==2252== 
==2252== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==2252==    at 0x106EC: main (in /home/jesse/C/Proj. Euler/productGrid.elf)
==2252==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2252==    at 0x10656: main (in /home/jesse/C/Proj. Euler/productGrid.elf)
==2252== 
==2252== Invalid write of size 4
==2252==    at 0x106EC: main (in /home/jesse/C/Proj. Euler/productGrid.elf)
==2252==  Address 0x7e2b6c38 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==2252== 
==2252== 
==2252== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==2252==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x7E2B6C38
==2252==    at 0x106EC: main (in /home/jesse/C/Proj. Euler/productGrid.elf)
==2252==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==2252==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==2252==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==2252==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==2252==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==2252== 
==2252== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2252==     in use at exit: 413 bytes in 2 blocks
==2252==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 4,509 bytes allocated
==2252== 
==2252== 61 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
==2252==    at 0x483E380: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==2252==    by 0x48E188B: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==2252==    by 0x106C9: main (in /home/jesse/C/Proj. Euler/productGrid.elf)
==2252== 
==2252== 352 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 2
==2252==    at 0x483E380: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==2252==    by 0x48D11F3: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:69)
==2252==    by 0x10681: main (in /home/jesse/C/Proj. Euler/productGrid.elf)
==2252== 
==2252== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2252==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2252==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2252==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2252==    still reachable: 413 bytes in 2 blocks
==2252==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2252== 
==2252== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2252== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
Segmentation fault
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `i` is used uninitialised here `str_array[i] = token; 
                ++i;`.

Comment: @alk: Real stupid of me! That must have happened when I moved it. Thanks! No more valgrind errors, but grid is still getting corrupted.

Comment: Please not that by default Valgrind tests heap memory access *only*. So the stack allocated array(s) are **not** tested for out-of-bound access.

Comment: On how to do stack checking using Valgrind you might like to read this http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/sg-manual.html

Comment: Very important to know, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is used uninitialised here:

```
  str_array[i] = token; 
  ++i;
```

---

Note:

If you compile with symbols (option `-g` to GCC) then Valgrind annotates its logging with references to the source lines.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so I post a new answer. As @alk said, `i` it's uninitialized and if you just initialize it at the definition, the while won't work. Use a `for(;;)`, as you need the assignment.

Update your code if you are still having issues.

Comment: Reading it again, you take it to `STR_LEN` so you are accessing outside the array.

Comment: It reaches 20; the condition ends on 20, but the `while` has some other increments.

Comment: You are writing str_array[] from i = 20 to 39... there's a SIGSEGV there.. Most probably it's not raising because you overwrite another variable's memory.

Comment: Assuming everything else works: `i` starts at `0`, the while iterates until it reaches 20, the for loop resets it and iterates up to 20 again (not 19), when the next line is read, the while loop does not modify the start point, so it starts at 20, up to 40, and the cycle repeats from the for loop.

Comment: @Mander I get you now. I am now declaring and initialising  `i` just before the while loop, so that is no longer an issue. Thanks a lot! (I'll update my code)

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize i at the beginning.

Also about this piece of code:

```
while ((token = strsep(&str, " "))){
    str_array[i] = token;   //add token to str_array
    ++i;
 }

for (i = 0; i < STR_LEN; ++i){
     grid[line][i] = atol(str_array[i]);
     printf("grid[%d][%d]: %d\n", line, i, grid[line][i]);
}
```

why are you counting the i if you are going to zero it below? Maybe you should use a different counter and loop until this and not STR_LEN.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see.. About the for loop if you have put in str_array less than STR_LEN this will not work. You should check how many you have inserted I think..

Comment: Thankfully I know that I will always get 20 numbers from each line in the file :)

Comment: Really good suggestion by the way, if I didn't know how many I would get from each line, this would be vital. Deserves an upvote, so +1 ; )